# Does anyone know the name for graphical word charts?

Tags: charts, graphics

These things were very popular a few years back. They showed different words (or phrases) in different font sizes and jumbled all over the screen. The idea was that the most important words (depending on criteria) would appear more prominently. The text would often go vertically as well as horizontally. Colours were also often used for effect.

I just want to know what these charts were called and if there are any free tools for generating them. Many thanks.

Comment: google has a free [word tree chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree)...

Comment: Thank you for looking. Unfortunately that wasn't quite what I was after as the tree signifies structure. The word diagrams I remember were like someone dropped 20 words onto a black sheet of paper. Some words were larger than others, Some went vertically and some horizontally. Those words that stood out most were larger and more important to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out they're called "Word Clouds". There seems to be a few generators for them on the web so I won't list them.